# Trying to get property of non-object in Laravel 5 after upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created my first Laravel package out of some old PHP script for Teamspeak auth service. The main app was running Laravel 4, but has now been upgraded to Laravel 5. My package worked before, but now does not.

The error -

```
[2017-08-17 22:04:29] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /apppath/vendor/eveseat/services/src/Settings/Settings.php:86
Stack trace:
#0 /apppath/vendor/eveseat/services/src/Settings/Settings.php(86): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/apppath/$
#1 /apppath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(349): Seat\Services\Settings\Settings::Seat\Services\Settings\{closure}()
#2 /apppath/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php(301): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->rememberForever('tHKT2R21Aa1VLKh...', Object(Closure))
#3 /apppath/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(6468): Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager->__call('rememberForever', Array)
#4 /apppath/vendor/eveseat/services/src/Settings/Settings.php(101): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('rememberForever', Array)
#5 /apppath/vendor/eveseat/services/src/Helpers/helpers.php(289): Seat\Services\Settings\Settings::get('main_character_...')
#6 /apppath/vendor/package/mypackage/src/Http/Controllers/Ts3Controller.php(33): setting('main_character_...')
#7 [internal function]: Seat\Ts3\Http\Controllers\Ts3Controller->getControls()
```

The offending function in Ts3Controller -

```
$APIcharacterID = $pheal->eveScope->CharacterID(array("names" => setting('main_character_name')));
```

The same call is made elsewhere in the parent package and still works, so the object still exists.

Pheal is not throwing errors and is completing API calls elswhere.

The Model being referenced -

```
namespace Seat\Services\Settings;

use Seat\Services\Models\UserSetting;
/**
 * Class Profile.
 * @package Seat\Services\Settings
 */
class Profile extends Settings
{
    /**
     * The options available for this Setting type.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $options = [
        'sidebar'            => ['sidebar-full', 'sidebar-collapse'],
        'skins'              => [
        'skin-blue', 'skin-black', 'skin-purple', 'skin-green',
        'skin-red', 'skin-yellow', 'skin-blue-light', 'skin-black-light',
        'skin-purple-light', 'skin-green-light', 'skin-red-light',
        'skin-yellow-light',
    ],
    'thousand_seperator' => [' ', ',', '.'],
    'decimal_seperator'  => [',', '.'],
    'mail_threads'       => ['yes', 'no'],
];
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected static $prefix = 'profile';
/**
 * @var
 */
protected static $model = UserSetting::class;
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected static $scope = 'user';
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected static $defaults = [
    // UI
    'sidebar'             => 'sidebar-full',
    'skin'                => 'skin-black',
    'language'            => 'en',
    'mail_threads'        => 'yes',
    // Main Character
    'main_character_id'   => 1,
    'main_character_name' => null,
    // Numbers
    'thousand_seperator'  => ' ',
    'decimal_seperator'   => '.',
    // Notifications
    'email_notifications' => 'no',
    // Multi factor authentication
    'require_mfa'         => 'no',
];
}
```

Which is referenced in my controller here -

```
use Seat\Services\Settings\Profile;
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel 5 have you upgraded to?

Comment: Those types of problems are pretty straight forward to fix. Just find the place in code which should create this object but instead is returning non object value.